# RMAN restore of primary database - impact on standby database

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, restore, rman, dataguard

I've just restored an 11g primary DB that was destroyed. Restored the controlfile from tape and performed a full restore, recovery, and open resetlogs. Looks fine now. How will my physical standby (using dataguard) handle this? When I 'show configuration' in dgmgrl I see:

```
Configuration - DG_Config

  Protection Mode: MaxPerformance
  Databases:
    TESTDB11  - Primary database
    TESTDB11A - Physical standby database
      Error: ORA-16810: multiple errors or warnings detected for the database

Fast-Start Failover: DISABLED

Configuration Status:
ERROR
```

How can I repair this standby after a restore of the primary?

---

This is the output from standby status report:

```
DGMGRL>  SHOW DATABASE 'TESTDB11A' 'StatusReport';
STATUS REPORT
       INSTANCE_NAME   SEVERITY ERROR_TEXT
                   *      ERROR ORA-16700: the standby database has diverged from the primary database
                   *      ERROR ORA-16766: Redo Apply is stopped
```

ORA-38726: Flashback database logging is not on.

Answer (score 1):

You *should* be able to use Flashback Database to get the standby back to the point in time (i.e. SCN) to which the primary was restored (Flashback Database is a requirement for automated failover).  If you can do this, then Data Guard *should* be able to wire things back up together again.

Have a look at these:

- http://www.br8dba.com/resetlogs-on-primary-where-standby-in-place/
- http://oracle-help.com/dataguard/flashback-database-after-resetlogs-in-data-guard/

If in doubt, though, or if you don't have Flashback Database enabled, then *trash* the standby and recreate it from scratch.

Comment: Many thanks Phill.